# How can I use a SplitArrayField in a ModelForm

Tags: python, django, postgresql, python-3.x

I am trying to show a postgresql ArrayField as multiple input fields in a form that users can submit data.

Lets say I had a model:

```
class Venue(models.Model):
    additional_links = ArrayField(models.URLField(validators=[URLValidator]), null=True)
```

That a form was using:

```
class VenueForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Venue
        exclude = ['created_date']
        widgets = {
            'additional_links': forms.Textarea(),
        }
```

How would I make the ArrayField use a SplitArrayField in the ModelForm?

I tried:

```
class VenueForm(forms.ModelForm):
    additional_links = SplitArrayField(forms.TextInput(), size=5, remove_trailing_nulls=True)

    class Meta:
    ..
```

and the same in the Meta class widgets:

```
    widgets = {
        'additional_links': forms.SplitArrayField(forms.TextInput(), size=3, remove_trailing_nulls=True)
    }
```

I also tried different form inputs/fields, but I always get the following error:

```
/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/postgres/forms/array.py", line 155, in __init__
    widget = SplitArrayWidget(widget=base_field.widget, size=size)
AttributeError: 'TextInput' object has no attribute 'widget'
```

Answer (score 1):

The SplitArrayField and SplitArrayWidget it is very different things.
Usage SplitArrayField in forms.ModelForm is adding a new field to a form.

The SplitArrayWidget is default widget for SplitArrayField, so you don`t need change it.

A problem is if you need set this widget to the field "additional_links", because value for the ArrayField must be comma-separated values without spaces.

**Example**:

*https://www.google.com,https://www.google.com.ru,https://www.google.com.ua*

Hence, the Django use django.forms.widgets.TextInput by default for ArrayField. It is very no comfortably for humans.

But if you still want use the SplitArrayWidget for the ArrayField you need modified this widget.

**My version:**

```
from django.contrib import postgres


class SplitInputsArrayWidget(postgres.forms.SplitArrayWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):

        value_from_datadict = super().value_from_datadict(data, files, name)

        # convert a list to a string, with commas-separated values
        value_from_datadict = ','.join(value_from_datadict)

        return value_from_datadict

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):

        # if object has value, then
        # convert a sting to a list by commas between values
        if value is not None:
            value = value.split(',')

        return super().render(name, value, attrs=None)
```

How to use it:

Model:

class Article(models.Model):
    """
    Model for article
    """

```
links = ArrayField(
    models.URLField(max_length=1000),
    size=MAX_COUNT_LINKS,
    verbose_name=_('Links'),
    help_text=_('Useful links'),
)
```

Form:

class ArticleAdminModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """

```
"""

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # field 'links'
    widget_base_field = self.fields['links'].base_field.widget
    count_inputs = self.fields['links'].max_length
    self.fields['links'].widget = SplitInputsArrayWidget(
        widget_base_field,
        count_inputs,
        attrs={'class': 'span12'}
    )
```

Result in the admin:

Django 1.10 (skin Django-Suit)
Python 3.4

[image: Without data]
[image: Filled data]

Useful links in web:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/contrib/postgres/forms/array/#SplitArrayField

https://bradmontgomery.net/blog/nice-arrayfield-widgets-choices-and-chosenjs/

More my widgets is in my new Django-project (see a file https://github.com/setivolkylany/programmerHelper/blob/master/utils/django/widgets.py)

Unfortunately right now this code without tests, so late I will update my answer.